# How to discover the object type in perl?

Tags: perl

Scenario:

- have several objects, created from `My::Module` and `Path::Class` and like...
- each object *can* return some string value calling an `specific method`
- need build an `HashRef` where the `values` are strings,

so something like (very shortened):

```
package Some;
sub filename { file('/tmp/xxx') }   #Path::Class the filename->stringify' returns the string value
sub myobj { My::Module->new(....) } #the myobj->stringvalue returns the string value
sub text { 'some text' }

sub data {
    my $strhr;
    $strhr->{$_} = $self->make_string $self->$_ for(qw(filename myobj text));
    return $strhr;
}

sub make_string {
    my($self, $val) = @_;
    return $val->stringify if( VAL_IS_PATH::CLASS_OBJ ); #need help here
    return $val->stringvalue if( VAL_IS_My::Obj_OBJ ); #and here
    return $val if( VAL_IS_SIMPLE_STRING ); #and here
    croak "unknown value";
}
```

In the real code the `filename` and `myobj` are defined with Moose, like:

```
has 'myobj' => (isa => 'My::Module', builder => ... ...);
```

But IMHO doing some Moose-ish `deep-coercion` is in this case much more complicated than make a simple `make_string` filter sub. But, i'm opened to any recommented solution...

So, the question is - how discover what object is the `$val`, or if it is an simple `Str`.

**EDIT**:

Based on *@David W.*'s comment i got the next:

```
sub make_string {
    my($self, $val) = @_;
    my $vref = ref $val;   #for the "text"  returns the string itself
    return $val->stringify if( $vref =~ /^Path::Class/ ); #works
    return $val->stringvalue if( $vref =~ /^My::Module/ ); #works
    return $val if( VAL_IS_SIMPLE_STRING ); #returns the string itself, so how to check this???
    croak "unknown value";
}
```

Comment: There's a Perl function called [ref](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) that will return the object type, and if it's a reference to a _blessed_ object, return the object name. [Scalar::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html) has a similar function called `blessed` that will return the object type, and unlike `ref`, won't return anything but the blessed object type. Will either of those work for you?

Comment: Don't use `ref`. If somebody creates a child class of Path::Class, your code won't recognise it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `isa` method. It's defined in the UNIVERSAL package (see `perldoc UNIVERSAL`). All Perl classes implicitly inherit from UNIVERSAL.

```
use Scalar::Util qw( blessed );

if (blessed($val) and $val->isa('Path::Class')) {
    print "It's a Path::Class object!\n";
}
```